# URL differences in anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net

What is the difference between the Following html links

```
<a href="home.aspx">
<a href="../home.aspx">
<a href="~/home.aspx">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <a href="home.aspx">

This redirects to `home.aspx` where home is in the same path location as the current page. So lets say I click that link while I am on http://example.com/subpath/about.aspx, I would get redirected to http://example.com/subpath/home.aspx. Likewise for http://example.com/subpath/subpath/about.aspx I would get redirected to http://example.com/subpath/subpath/home.aspx.

> <a href="../home.aspx">

This works very similar to the one above, but it always goes one level up in the path. The two dots means "one level up from here". Using the same examples:

- http://example.com/subpath/about.aspx -> http://example.com/home.aspx
- http://example.com/subpath/subpath/about.aspx -> http://example.com/subpath/home.aspx.

You can use it multiple times, too, if you need, such as `<a href="../../home.aspx">`.

> <a href="~/home.aspx">

The previous two are standard things that the browser understands and supports. This one is handled by ASP.NET. The tilde (`~`) specifies the [virtual root](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths) of your application. How this behaves is entirely dependent on how your application starts up and what the "root" of your site is. Put simply, the virtual root means "the top level location in your ASP.NET application". So, assuming that your site is configured so that the virtual root is the domain, it would behave like this:

- http://example.com/subpath/about.aspx -> http://example.com/home.aspx
- http://example.com/subpath/subpath/about.aspx -> http://example.com/home.aspx.